# Adding different views to UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[image]

In my app, i have addressbook which has a tableview to list contacts and in the right panel, i display the contact detail. In my contact detail page, i have fields like email, cellphone, workphone and homephone etc., and i have separate UIView for each field like cellphone, workphone etc., The Concept is to display the UIview of cellphone or workphone or such field only if there is a value for it. So its better to do it with a tableview right. My question is, can we add the UIView of those fields to the tableViewCell? i have attached the screenshot of the normal view. can i implement tableview here and add the UIView of each field to tableViewCell?

Comment: create different custom cell as par you Need else you can create also programmatic with condition of you want inexPath of cell that you want to change view.

Comment: can u pls show some light with the coding..?

Comment: @ManojEllappan, what you have tried so far.

Comment: custom cell http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: if you're using table view cell then there is no need of uiview putting inside of it you can reuse the same cell with different data.

Answer (score 0):

Create different custom cell for the different types you need and they should be with different identifiers. Then you can create a method that takes the correct identifier:

```
- (NSString *)identifierForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (someCondition) {
      return @"youCellIdentifier";
   } else if (otherCondition) {
      return @"yourCellOtherIdentifier";
   }
}
```

Then you can use this method in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If you have questions concerning this, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
CellView.frame=CGrectMake(0,0,150,50);
HomeView.frame=CGrectMake(0,60,150,50);
WorkView.frame=CGrectMake(0,120,150,50);
EmailView.frame=CGrectMake(0,180,150,50);



[Cell.contentview addsubview:cellview];
[Cell.contentview addsubview:HomeView];
[Cell.contentview addsubview:WorkView];
[Cell.contentview addsubview:EmailView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom `UITableViewCells`:

- In your storyboard, create prototype cells. Drag there the elements you want for the different kinds of cells and position them appropriately. In your example, you will need one prototype cell for the blue cells and another one for the gray cell.
- Subclass `UITableViewCell`. Create new Objective-C class for the new kinds of cells and select `UITableViewCell` as superclass.
- Link the storyboard and the new classes. Go to the storyboard and select the cells. Enter as cell class the names of the newly created classes (instead of the default `UITableViewCell`. Create `IBOutlets` for the elements in the cells.
- In your view controller, when creating new cells, set the values for the cell elements.

Hope, that helps you.